# How to view sales per minute on tiny death star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I know how to navigate to spm on tiny tower but am unable do do so on tiny death star. Also does sales per minute mean purchases per minute or total profit per minute. If it just means sales per minute how can I view profit per minute.

Comment: I'm not certain this function exists on TDS. I've never seen it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of `Version: 1.2.2344` this function does not exist in Tiny Death Star.

Answer (score 2):

That feature is only Tiny Tower, not in Tiny Death Star although I think that they might add that feature later. But, if it is added later you go to the menu and click the floor icon and it will show the number of a certain type of floor and sales per min thats how it works on Tiny Tower

Comment: Well that's quite disappointing